# Web.py behaves differently when run from IDLE or command line

Tags: python, python-2.6, web.py

I've been experimenting with hosting a simple webservice using web.py in python 2.6.6 and have run into an interesting problem - my code works fine when run in IDLE but if I execute the same via the command line (python.exe mycode.py) the web.py app launches (I see the text http://0.0.0.0:8080/ on the console)  then launches again on the first web request (I see the text http://0.0.0.0:8080/ a second time) - only by pressing ctrl-C does the code start to work and return the response to the web requests.  I'm using the latest web.py (0.37) and the python version (2.6.6) is forced by other constraints in my project.

```
import web

    class hello:        
        def GET(self, name):
            return 'Hello'

    urls = ('/Hello(.*)', 'hello')
    app = web.application(urls, globals())

    app.run()
```

I've spent the afternoon searching for similar problems but I'm stumped - can anyone recreate the problem at least?

Comment: Took a while but I realized I was missing this from the example:

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()

The code now runs as expected in both IDLE and the command line

Answer (score 0):

Took a while but I realized I was missing this from the example: if name == "main": app = web.application(urls, globals()) app.run() The code now runs as expected in both IDLE and the command line